# javaScript json как получить доступ к объекту

Tags: javascript, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как получить доступ к объекту name указанному на скриншоте?

Comment: Там нет объекта name, там строка

Comment: `obj['1172620'].data.name`

Comment: уже пробовал, не выходит

Comment: entithat, спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выведенный объект сохранён в переменную `x`, то:

```
x[1172620].data.name
```

Если нужен первый ключ, но его название неизвестно, то

```
x[Object.keys(x)[0]].data.name
```